# Want to use Genemu FormBundle autocomplete with querybuilder

Tags: jquery, symfony

I'd like to use the following code with Genemy FormByndle so that I can use autocomplete in my form:

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

I tried that:

```
$builder
  ->add('user', 'genemu_jqueryautocomplete_entity', array(
        'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
       'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
         },
     ))
```

but query_builder is not a parameter in genemu_jqueryautocomplete_entity.

Is there a way to extend that?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the query builder result in action and call the route in **genemu_jqueryautocomplete**

here is some example:

```
 $builder ->add('users','genemu_jqueryautocomplete_text', array(
                    'route_name' => 'retrieve_users_name',
            ));
```

and i have an action with `retributive_users_name` route:
`

```
/**
 * @Route("/retrieve-users-name", name="retrieve_users_name")
 */
public function retrieve_users_nameAction(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->get('term');

    //retriving users
    $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XYBundle:User')
                                     ->findByValue($value);
    // convert the result to array
    $search = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
    $search[$user->getId()] = $user->getName();
    }

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->setContent(json_encode($search));

    return $response;
}
```

and write your querybuilder in getByValue function in UserRepository.